# Unable to connect to MySQL VM from host machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, mysql, telnet, ubuntu-18.04

I have an `Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop 64 bit` host machine.

On this host machine, I have used VirtualBox to create an `Ubuntu 18.04 Server 64 bit VM`, and have installed MySQL on it, created a MySQL user, a database, and a table.

I have set the network adaptor in this VM to `Bridged Adaptor`.

On the host machine, if I type:

```
telnet <VM IP Address> <MySQL port number>
```

I get the following error message:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

What have I missed out in the configuration?

Comment: what is the output of `netstat -anutp | grep :<MySQL port number>` on the Ubuntu server? this will show you where MySql is listening.

Comment: @Zina The output is `tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 995/mysqld`.  The IP Address of the VM server is 192.168.0.19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MySQL server inside the VM is bound only on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`).

To connect from your desktop, you need it to be listening on the bridged network interface, though it's easiest just to have it listen on *all* interfaces.

Modify your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (or wherever your my.cnf can be found) so that you either uncomment or add the following line:

`bind-address     = 0.0.0.0`

within the `[mysqld]` section so it looks like the following:

```
...
[mysqld]
bind-address     = 0.0.0.0
...
```

If you are having trouble finding your my.cnf, the places MySQL searches in Unix and Unix-Like Systems is:

```
File Name                Purpose
/etc/my.cnf              Global options
/etc/mysql/my.cnf        Global options
SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf        Global options
$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf       Server-specific options (server only)
defaults-extra-file      The file specified with --defaults-extra-file, if any
~/.my.cnf                User-specific options
~/.mylogin.cnf           User-specific login path options (clients only)
DATADIR/mysqld-auto.cnf  System variables persisted with SET PERSIST or SE PERSIST_ONLY (server only)
```

Note some distributions also assign their own locations (e.g. `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`)

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html for more information.

Comment: This fixed the problem.  Thanks.